# Allow ec2:CreateSecurityGroup only if request contain specific tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-security-group, aws-policies

I'm trying to write a IAM policy to ensure that a resource (a security group in the example) can't be created unless it is tagged with a specific tag with a specific value.

Here is my policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:GetConsole*",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/CreatedBy": "a_value"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the relevant part in the web console:

[image: web console]

When i click on "create security group" I get this error:

[image: web console error]

Here the decoded error:

```json
{
    "allowed": false,
    "explicitDeny": false,
    "matchedStatements": {
        "items": []
    },
    "failures": {
        "items": []
    },
    "context": {
        "principal": {
            "id": "<redacted>",
            "name": "<redacted>",
            "arn": "<redacted>"
        },
        "action": "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
        "resource": "<redacted>",
        "conditions": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "key": "aws:Region",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "eu-west-1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Service",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "ec2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Resource",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "<redacted>"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Type",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "vpc"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Account",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "<redacted>"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:Tenancy",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "default"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:VpcID",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "<redacted>"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:Region",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "eu-west-1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:ARN",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "<redacted>"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `Condition` block, it works. Any Idea?

**EDIT**
Here what I have on cloudtrail:

```json
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "<redacted>",
        "arn": "<redacted>",
        "accountId": "<redacted>",
        "accessKeyId": "<redacted>",
        "userName": "<redacted>",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {},
            "webIdFederationData": {},
            "attributes": {
                "creationDate": "2023-03-29T08:48:59Z",
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2023-03-29T15:49:45Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateSecurityGroup",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "<redacted>",
    "userAgent": "AWS Internal",
    "errorCode": "Client.UnauthorizedOperation",
    "errorMessage": "You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: br3mkxwSe4g18HaPPrDGj_GbkhVzwkrOCNyUN8lcZ9psjAPxwYke-uBJD5HFjFZ4nZ0Yv84SFHezTDAiKQe3NnuGODXIvxilxmzSMDKFgsKM4VymOTu-2MobyTpUekHZhR0UK2uOw_GmW5ihIjUH3Nm_kVPVZ-n5_16KkZk2xeJwAZ_Ra5bhnBbCJm2Xaa_mrqZP5cL_il2PsSNvMep_fFyJeD7MjpzA9T3bpVmOdjoHR9bjMvOJHB2IpgeXnFiJlgTvHwQYYoJtsl-wcFKI8Ra9yz5kgpzXIlvWbmxyZPLj0L8r0cd4qyrBesKd6IdFABJR01FEdp0WOF0Er-UdCYwDabKTH-VrbBnQOcehMOQNTNYsv-rVHBOfjkd5U_ccgCBKj5NkT3Sc0uDYYw9yBLoaVOS830LSvVMEVFIzQ_3eunVU44ktsYnveP5PLgiIYZ_skQHx5Y9kAtkAo-dnCsumXW1P32XqDc9gaETxHNG13MOGo5Hu8F0mYeJH_tY0MYq5iW54pDCfW0CywZvfVRgfbIK9tURhz6JkJBA2p7rR0jU",
    "requestParameters": {
        "groupName": "whatever_name",
        "groupDescription": "whatever_description",
        "vpcId": "<redacted>",
        "tagSpecificationSet": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "resourceType": "security-group",
                    "tags": [
                        {
                            "key": "CreatedBy",
                            "value": "a_value"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "<redacted>",
    "eventID": "<redacted>",
    "readOnly": false,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "<redacted>",
    "eventCategory": "Management",
    "sessionCredentialFromConsole": "true"
}
```

Comment: I notice that there is no Tag in the decoded error. It is possible that the console creates the Security Group first and then adds the Tag later. You could look in CloudTrail to see the exact request that was sent.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've edited the question with the CloudTrail entry

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```json
{
    "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:RequestTag/CreatedBy": "a_value"
        }
    },
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-ID>:security-group/*"
},
{
    "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:RequestTag/CreatedBy": "a_value"
        }
    },
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-ID>:security-group/*"
}
```

---

[This AWS document was useful when I was addressing this problem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_securitygroups-vpc.html).

I had this issue a few months ago, so I'm a little fuzzy on the details but I have a working policy; I'll break it down into statements:

`CreateSecurityGroup` on your specified VPC (if applicable)

```json
{
  "Action": "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-ID>:vpc/vpc-1234"
}
```

In my experience, the security group is created and then `CreateTags` is called immediately after, but in a separate action -- therefore both `CreateSecurityGroup` and `CreateTags` require the condition.

```json
{
    "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:RequestTag/CreatedBy": "a_value"
        }
    },
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-ID>:security-group/*"
}
```

This should get you to your desired behaviour.

---

#### Below is useful to prevent the removal of the tag

Note that this next statement is a `Deny`.

*Sadly we have to do `security-group/*` in the resource field and can't be more specific.*

```json
{
    "Action": "ec2:DeleteTags",
    "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
            "aws:TagKeys": "CreatedBy"
        }
    },
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-ID>:security-group/*"
}
```